# Быстро ли работает тернарный оператор Java?

Tags: java, оптимизация

Что быстрее :

```
x = boolean ? 3 : 5;
```

или :

```
if (boolean) x = 3;
else x = 5;
```

?

Comment: Начинающие программисты стараются оптимизировать программу, еще ее не написав, там, где это не требуется. Компилятор может вообще эти две конструкции перевести в один и тот байт-код.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Не может перевести, а переведет. Почти гарантировано это будет аналогичный байт-код, но сомневающиеся могут и проверить.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Время выполнения обеих конструкций будет одинаково, так как при компиляции обеих конструкций (*с вероятностью, близкой к единице*) Вы получите один и тот же байт-код.

Тернарный условный оператор – это т.н. *синтаксический сахар*, который просто сокращает запись и в некоторых случаях таким образом предоставляет удобство для программиста, *но не более того*.